# MySQL CS 8.0.13 update time is always null

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Wasn't an issue with UPDATE_TIME in InnoDB since 5.0.18 solved? I run MySQL server ver. 8.0.13. I've updated my 3 tables with Workbench and with python script. Data was updated, but no info about it.

`UPDATE_TIME` is always `Null`

Syntax for updating table:

`UPDATE tabcustomer SET cusEmail = %(value)s WHERE cusId =%(id)s`

Syntax for reading update_time

```
SELECT update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='garibaldi'
AND table_name='abbcards';
```

My full script must be binded with UPDATE_TIME value. Is there any solution except moving  DB on MyISAM engine?

**UPDATE:**

columns from `information_schema.tables`

```
TABLE_NAME  
abbcards

TABLE_TYPE  
BASE TABLE

ENGINE
InnoDB

TABLE_ROWS
250  

CREATE_TIME
26.11.2018 12:04:17

UPDATE_TIME 
(null)

CHECK_TIME  
(null)
```

Comment: [MySQL version 8.0.12](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n56U5r24mc9D3muygBLxgP/0) seams to be working fine, I find i hard to believe it does not work in MySQL 8.0.13

Comment: I'm not familiar with the feature but there's a comment in [8.0 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-0.html#mysqld-8-0-0-data-dictionary) that says "For INFORMATION_SCHEMA queries that retrieve table statistics, the server now can use statistics cached in INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, or obtain the latest statistics directly from storage engines. The information_schema_stats system variable controls which statistics source the server uses." Indeed, I only get stall stats in my system.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Interesting. I updated my question.